# Update a cell in datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm working on a winform application where a user can add values to a datagridview.I can add the data fine, however I am stuck on how to update a value directly in the cell. I want to be able to update a cell in the datagrid which in turn would update a second cell.

**CellQuantity * CellTotalValue**
[image]
Code:

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    string articleId = cmbArticle.Text;
    string productDescription = txtDesc.Text;
    string type = txtType.Text;
    string materialType = txtMaterial.Text;
    string size = cmbSizes.Text;
    string quantity = txtQuantity.Text;
    string total = txtTotal.Text;

    try
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            //addrows
            dr["Article"] = articleId;
            dr["Description"] = productDescription;
            dr["type"] = type;
            dr["Material"] = materialType;
            dr["Size"] = size;
            dr["Quantity"] = quantity;
            dr["total"] = total;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dgvView.DataSource = dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

How can I go about achieving this? Thank you.

Comment: where is the original DataTable..? this is what  you want to work against then rebind..

Comment: The DataTable is declared at class level, can you explain what you mean please?

Comment: ok..then  when you do dgvView.DataSource = dt add a line that binds that data `dgvView.DataBind()`

Comment: Datatable allows you to create a column that holds an expression, you can define the expression at design time - See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwxk25bd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/447249/Calculated-Columns-in-NET-DataTables-Csharp

Comment: `haris` let me write you a small sample I just tested editing the row that I have selected basically my example I do it on DataBound Event but you can get the gist I will post in one second

Comment: So by adding the dgvView.DataBind() would allow me to update the cell value directly and update the datatable? But I only get DataBindings and DataBindingsComplete to show in the intellisense?

Comment: no you want to do that when you want to show updated data I misunderstood your original issue hold one sec

Comment: Where do you store the price (2.99 value)?

Comment: The price value is being retrieve from the dataset, which is the datasource of the datatable

Comment: @EmmadKareem does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, somewhat. I proposed using an expression. This proposition works if the price is part of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it easily in `CellEndEdit` Event

put this on your form

```
        private void dgvView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
        dgvView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["TotalAmount"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantitiy"].Value) * Convert.ToDecimal(dgvView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["TotalAmount"].Value);
    }
```

so whenever `Quanitity` cell or `TotalAmount` cell is edited the cell will be calculated and updated

dont't forget to check for null but that should be self explanatory

Comment: THANKS! this is exactly what I was after, but now... I have this issue, if I edit the quantity value... it multiplies it by the current totalvalue and not the base value e.g  2 * 10 = 20, if I edit to quantity to 3 now the total = 60. How can I only times it by inital 10?

Comment: No worries I figured it out. Thanks again!

Comment: that is because you have 2 columns only actually you should do this with three otherwise you don't have the exact UnitPrice. you can circumvent this by having the UnitPrice somewhere on the form or hidden in a variable. The Problem is mainly if your Quantity starts with 2 then your unitprice will be TotalAmount/2... best is to split it up in 3 columns